# Append columns to rows satisfying certain conditions

Tags: r, csv, rows, output

I'm new to SO, and to the R programming language.

I have two datasets in csv format. They each contain several columns. Let's say:
- the 1st file a.csv contains columns A, B, C, D
- the 2nd file b.csv contains columns A, B, Y, Z

I would like to output all the rows for which A, B contain the same values in both files (condition) into a new output.csv file, and append Y, Z from b.csv to C, D from a.csv only for the rows which satisfied that (condition).

Here is an example:

a.csv

```
    A      B      C      D
    1      a      0      1
    56     b      2      3
    321    b      0      0
```

b.csv

```
    A      B      Y      Z
    1      a      4      4
    56     b      5      5
    321    o      0      10
```

output.csv

```
    A      B      C      D      Y      Z
    1      a      0      1      4      4
    56     b      2      3      5      5
```

I've been trying stuff for several hours but nothing outputs exactly what I want. I'd be really grateful to learn from your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with merge -

```
output <- merge(a, b, by.x=c(1,2))
```

For additional info check ?merge